# check if value exist in json file using php

Tags: php, json

i make a login system using php with json file data. i tried to login with JavaScript file and it works fine. but it is not secure well. then i change some code with php login. 
this is my php code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $json_string = file_get_contents('login.json');
    $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);

    foreach($parsed_json as $key => $value){
        $jsonemail = $value['email'];
        $jsonpass = $value['pass'];
    }
        if($email == $jsonemail && $pass == $jsonpass){
                header('location: view.php');
        }
        else{
            echo "please check your email or password";
        }   
}
```

but this not working. i want to fix this code. i want to check email and password is correct with json file data.

this is my login.json file data like

```
  "1": {       
    "email": "test123@gmail.com",
    "pass": "123"
   },
```

and this is my html login form

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required="require" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pass">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" required="require" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" >Submit</button>
                </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If you look for help, help too in providing more information

Comment: i edit my question and added more information. sorry for issue

Comment: yes $parsed_json getting data

Comment: Can you show that data as is. in your question?

Comment: i think my foreach loop is something wrong for check data is exist

Comment: Array ( [1] => Array ( [email] => test123@gmail.com [pass] => 123 ) )

Comment: Ok let me try with this

Comment: Please check my answer. I dissected your code to correct in several ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your email and pass variable are not defined. Have a look at it.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $json_string = file_get_contents('login.json');
    $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);
    $email       = $_POST['email']; // I think you miss this
    $pass        = $_POST['pass']; // and this lines as in your code its missing
    $flag        = false;
    foreach ($parsed_json as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['email'] == $email && $value['pass'] == $pass) {
            $flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($flag) {
        header('location: view.php');
    } else {
        echo "Please check your email and password."
    }
}
```

And one more thing

while posting any form you must name element which you want in $_POST.

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" required="require" placeholder="Password">
```

In above line you are missing name as `pass`. Replace above line with

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" required="require" placeholder="Password" name="pass">
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: i think some issue with my foreach loop

Comment: how to find exist values in a json file using php

Comment: i fixed my issue. password field name is not given me.

Comment: Just to point out that if you had 2 records in the JSON and tried to log in as the first one, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` is just overwriting the values of $jsonemail and $jsonpass each time, so when you reach the `if()` part to check the user details, these will always be the last values in the file.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $json_string = file_get_contents('login.json');
    $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);

    foreach($parsed_json as $key => $value){
        if($email == $value['email'] && $pass == $value['pass']){
            header('location: view.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
    echo "please check your email or password";
}
```

This code redirects if the user is found and if it gets to the end of the loop, then the user doesn't exist in the file.

Comment: i tried this one but it's not working. always show check email and password

Comment: Sorry - missed out a close }, added this just before the last echo.

Comment: I assume your setting the field values (`$email` from `$_POST['email']` and similar for password)

Comment: And your password (as rahulsm points out you don't have a name for the password field in your HTML)?